# Multiple DataContext bindings in UWP Page and CommandBar

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp

I need to bind some specific elements in my UWP page to a different VIewModel than what the page has.
So in my page I bind to one DataContext:

```
<Page
    DataContext="{Binding RootViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
...
```

and I am now trying to bind the bottomAppBar CommandBar to a different ViewModel:

```
  <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar DataContext="{Binding OtherViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
            <CommandBar.Content>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>
```

But it doesn't work, the binding does not occur in the CommandBar.
Why?

Comment: To the anonymous coward down voter: why did you down vote? Please leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, the `DataContext` of the `CommandBar` doesn't get passed to its `Content`. Actually, *only* the `DataContext` property of a child element will automatically get the same `DataContext` of its parent, unless you specifically break the flow by assigning another value to it.

In your case, the `DataContext` of your `CommandBar` will be `OtherViewModel`, but the `Content` property will remain `null`.

So instead of manually setting the `DataContext`, you should set its `Content` instead.

```
<CommandBar Content="{Binding OtherViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
    <CommandBar.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CommandBar.ContentTemplate>

    ...
</CommandBar>
```